What is the purpose of this pull up/pull down do in this circuit and how does it work
I'm working on debugging a Hardware OVP/OCP circuitry of a motor controller unit from this reference guide, I'm unable to understand how does the OCP Circuit work.

How is the OCP circuit with the Pull up/ pull down resistor of 680k Ohms (R85, R94) calculated?
How does the OCP work in the positive and negative current limit set by the threshold voltage?





What are OCP and OVP?

@jonathanjo probably over-voltage protection, and over-current protection

The circuit consists of two sections- one for each polarity- that have a wired-OR output so a low signal at nMEG represents a current exceeding the set limits.
Consider the positive section- the voltage at TP51 will be the highest of the three inputs minus about 50mV for the Schottky diode drop. That is divided down by about 0.591 via the 470kΩ and 680kΩ resistors and compared to a 2.25V reference derived from the 5V rail via the R86/R87 divider connected to the non-inverting input of comparator IC27A. So if the voltage at any of the three inputs exceeds (2.25/0.591)+0.05V = 3.86V then output nMEG will go low.
The negative section works similarly, however the voltage is divided to the positive rail and the reference is divided off the positive rail so that when the voltage at any of the three inputs is less than
-((2.25/0.591)+0.05V) then the output of comparator IC27B will go low. Note that the reference is connected to the inverting input of IC27B.
So the net result is that nMEG is low iff (|ADU| > 3.86V) || (|ADV| > 3.86V) || (|ADW| > 3.86V)
... where |x| represents absolute value and || represents logical-OR.

This 3-phase design measures peak voltage from the current sensors for each polarity.
If the peak voltage exceeds Vref (TP54+, TP55-) in either polarity, OCP can then be asserted or used to control the PWM servo.
